# VBA: Summing a matrix

Tags: excel, matrix, vba

Why doesn't this function work?

Type `=funtest(2.1)` in Excel and it'll give me `#VALUE!`.

```
Public Function funtest(a As Double) As Double

Dim z, j, i As Integer
Dim matrix(3, 3, 3) As Double

For z = 0 To 3 Step 1
For j = 0 To 3 Step 1
For i = 0 To 3 Step 1

matrix(z, j, i) = a

Next i, j, z

funtest = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(matrix)

End Function
```

Comment: I believe that the Sum function takes a range as input, not a VBA Array of Double.

Comment: what are your trying to accomplish with this function?

Comment: @brettdj The object that I created called `matrix` is a 3-dimensions array with `(3,3,3)` dimensions. I want to sum each and every element in this matrix. Calling the function as `funtest(2.1)` is arbitrary with respect to `2.1`. I just want to test if it works with any `double`. My actual problem is more complicated, but I'm trying to solve the simple case of a `(3,3,3)` matrix with each element equal to some double, `a`, before I progress further.

Comment: I never knew you could put Next i, j, z all on one line like that!  +1 just for that.

Comment: @Harokitty you dont need the Step 1. Only use Step if your increments are more than one or if you are decrementing use the Step -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WorksheetFunction.Sum` will work with either a range or a 2 dimentional array.  It errors because you are passing it a 3 dimensional array.

So, this works

```
Public Function funtest(a As Double) As Double
    Dim z As Long, j As Long, i As Long
    Dim matrix() As Double

    ReDim matrix(0 To 3, 0 To 4)
    For j = LBound(matrix, 1) To UBound(matrix, 1)
    For i = LBound(matrix, 2) To UBound(matrix, 2)
        matrix(j, i) = a
    Next i, j

    funtest = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(matrix)
End Function
```

Note I have modified your declarations slighly, see note at end of answer.

To sum higher dimensional arrays you will need to do some looping.

One option (which may or may not suit your overal requirements) is to declare your array slightly differently, as a so called `Jagged Array`.

```
Public Function funtest2(a As Double) As Double
    Dim z As Long, j As Long, i As Long
    Dim matrix() As Variant
    Dim InnerMatrix(0 To 4, 0 To 4) As Double

    ' Dimension Jagged Array
    ReDim matrix(0 To 4)
    For i = LBound(matrix, 1) To UBound(matrix, 1)
        matrix(i) = InnerMatrix
    Next

    'Load Data into matrix
    For z = LBound(matrix) To UBound(matrix)
    For j = LBound(matrix(z), 1) To UBound(matrix(z), 1)
    For i = LBound(matrix(z), 2) To UBound(matrix(z), 2)
        matrix(z)(j, i) = a
    Next i, j, z

    ' Sum matrix
    For z = LBound(matrix) To UBound(matrix)
        funtest2 = funtest2 + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(matrix(z))
    Next
End Function
```

This is an array of 2 dimensional arrays. The `Sum` is then applied to each of the inner arrays in turn. This way, at least you are only looping one dimension and not all three.

Note on `Dim` and `Integer`
You must specify all `As Type`'s, otherwise variables default to `Variant`
In your code `z` and `j` will be `Variants`

Also, using `Integer` rather than `Long` is actually counter productive on a 32 bit OS: `Long`'s will be slightly faster.

Comment: And `Variants` are slower. In VBA, it doesn't hurt to turn on static typing by adding `Option Explicit` to the beginning of the Module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take you literally when you say "I'm trying to solve the simple case of a (3,3,3) matrix with each element equal to some double, a".  This will do that:

```
Public Function funtest(a As Double) As Double
   funtest = 4*4*4*a
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

First, when you get `#VALUE!` this means there is an error, it can mean using a matrix that is not valid.

To answer your question, your code does not work because your syntax is not correct. The following function creates a matrix from values.

```
Function FQ_matrix_create(StartValue As Double, Interval As Double,
nrow As Long, ncol As Long) As Double()
Dim M() As Double
' Creates matrix with sequential element values with given row and
' column sizes. Fills matrix row-wise with numbers.
' - set Interval = 0 for constant element values
' - error input arguments nrow and ncol are not positive integers
```

To SUM the Values use:

```
Function FQ_matrix_element_sum(M() As Double, SumOption As
MatrixDirection) As Double()
' Returns the sum of elements of matrix M, either row or column wise
' - Rowwise sum returns a horizontal 1xNcol matrix
' - Columnwise sum returns a vertical 1 xNrow matrix
' - Element sum (all elements) returns a 1x1 matrix
' - error if M is not a matrix
' - error if SumOption is not 1 (nRowWiseSum) or 2 (nColWiseSum) or
3 (nElementSum)
```

To help you understand Matrix in Excel VBA, here is a good resource: http://finaquant.com/download/matrixvectorvba

Specifically, take a look at the PDF Download on the site.

Comment: So there's no native functionality for matrices? How do these differ to multi-dimensioned arrays that I tried to make?

Comment: matrix function syntax is [{1,2,3; 4,5,6}] not (1,2,3)

Comment: I don't see how declaring a 2-d array of constants is relevant to the question asked.