# VBA Excel 2003/2007: Declaring, Filling, and Passing a Jagged Array

Tags: vba, excel

I have thoroughly researched this topic and have yet to find code that works to accomplish what I need to do.  In a nutshell, I'm creating a Production Tracking program and the feature of it on which I'm working now involves accurately tracking vacation days for 5 employees.  A userform containing 5 listboxes, one for each employee, is used to select which days each employee took off for the week.  The problem comes when I try to create unique dynamic arrays containing each employees' days off.  I figured out how to create an array that captures this information but it's one array that gets reassigned each time the loop iterates.  I need to have a unique array for each employee containing his days off to be used later in the code to adjust weekly scoring depending on his available days of work.  Below is my code in the userform for to create a create the jagged array:

```
Public Name_Jagged() As Variant

For Each Name In Name_Array
    Set Unique_Listbox = Controls(Name & "_Vacation")
    For UnSelected = 0 To Unique_Listbox.ListCount - 1
        If Unique_Listbox.Selected(UnSelected) = False Then
            ReDim Preserve Name_Jagged(0 To UBound(Name_Jagged) + 1)
            Name_Array(Name) = Name_Jagged()
            Name_Jagged(UBound(Name_Jagged)) = Unique_Listbox.List(UnSelected)
        End If
        For UnSelected_Array_Pos = LBound(Name_Jagged) To UBound(Name_Jagged)
            MsgBox Name & "_" & Name_Jagged(UnSelected_Array_Pos)
        Next UnSelected_Array_Pos
    Next UnSelected
Next Name
```

The compiler will not allow me to use Public Name_Jagged()() As Variant either despite most other forums saying this is how it's supposed to be written.  The only other post I found online regarding this jagged array declaration issue was not answered.

I would really appreciate your help.  I've been able to figure out everything so far from previous threads but this has eluded me.  If there is a better option than jagged arrays to accomplish this, I'm all ears.  I read in some forums about using Lists but I am not at all familiar with them or how to use them at this point.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Here are a couple of other answers about Jagged Arrays that might help [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18542133/445425) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20793748/445425) [three](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12382183/445425)

Comment: You can *reference* nested functions, properties and arrays in VBA with expressions like `variable = Name_Jagged()()`.  This works, I've done it.  What you can *not* do is to directly *declare* a nested array in VBA.  So this: `Public Name_Jagged()() As Variant` is illegal syntax and any forum that said that it works is wrong.  The only ways to construct nested arrays in VBA are manual: though Variants or user Classes that implement an array-like interface.

Comment: Note:  the reference form i mentioned above should be `variable = Name_Jagged(i)(j)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought but why have 5 static listboxes for each employee?
Why not just have 1 list box which contains the names of the employees and 1 list box which contains the days of the week.  You highlight the employee you want and than select the days which they've taken off.  Hit a submit button which would load the employees name into an array with the days selected? The array could be structured like this

> NAME | MONDAY | TUESDAY | WEDNESDAY | THURSDAY | FRIDAY | SATURDAY | SUNDAY
>
> > JIM.....   OFF............  OFF
> >
> > ERIC.......................OFF.............OFF

And so on.  This way if you need to add people in the future you just add them to the list box.  You would than have one simple array to deal with?

Also you said "to be used later in the code to adjust weekly scoring depending on his available days of work"

A suggestion; You may want to consider logging it to a simple mysql/mssql database which gives you far more flexibility and control for the future.